# Hard refresh needed to display data in Umbraco.DateTime control

Tags: angularjs, umbraco, umbraco7

I have a custom section in Umbraco, when you click a node in my custom tree, the URL is correctly displayed and the data loads successfully.

When you then click another node in the tree (sibling, exactly the same controller and view)

All the data loads...... except for the data that should shown in the calender control. If I reload the page the data loads. [image]

For testing, I created and added an extra control but this time it is just a Umbraco.Textbox, and the data always loads correctly

So what is it about the Umbraco.DateTime all the other controls I have on the same page load drop downs, check boxes etc

Is there something I can do in my Angular(v1.6) controller to force these to update everytime?

**Update: Code in my view looks like this.**

```
                            <umb-property property="vm.endDateTimeTxt">
                            <umb-editor model="vm.endDateTimeTxt"></umb-editor>
                        </umb-property>

                        <umb-property property="vm.startDateTimePropertyEditor">
                            <umb-editor model="vm.startDateTimePropertyEditor"></umb-editor>
                        </umb-property>

                        <umb-property property="vm.endDateTimePropertyEditor">
                            <umb-editor model="vm.endDateTimePropertyEditor"></umb-editor>
                        </umb-property>
```

And For the Umbraco.DatePicker controls this is the method that genrates the property editor

```
function buildUmbracoClockPropertyEditor(alias, editor, view, label, description, config, mandatory = true) {
            return {
                editor: "Umbraco.DateTime",
                label: label,
                description: description,
                hideLabel: false,
                view: view,
                alias: alias,
                value: null,
                validation: {
                    mandatory: mandatory,
                    pattern: ""
                },
                config: {
                    pickDate: true,
                    pickTime: false,
                    useSeconds: false,
                    format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS",
                    icons: {
                        time: "icon-time",
                        date: "icon-calendar",
                        up: "icon-chevron-up",
                        down: "icon-chevron-down"
                    }
                },
            }
```

I have also updated the format of the string when it is loaded in to the text box so now this is before a hard refresh.

[image]

And this is after

[image]

So as you can see the data is there, it gets loaded in to the text box first time you click on a node, but required me to go to my browser address bar and press enter to get the dates to load in to the Umbraco.DateTime controls.

this is just nuts! the data is there, the format is the same... what else could it be!

Comment: Could you share the HTML in your view?

Comment: I'm thinking it might have something to do with the date format, maybe the Umbraco.DateTime control can't handle what you're inputting.

Comment: Yeah I tried the format thing... and now I am returning the data in the same format.... still no joy. - I'm going to start cutting my self next.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Umbraco is loading all javascript on load and we need to force it to load again.

I have tried to recycle AppPool, restart website, touch web.config etc. its not easy to reload it.